# Int null checker on a partial view

Tags: c#, nullable, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a partial view which does not have any parameters passed to it and is called by multiple apps.

I however want to change the requirements and pass a nullable `int` to it and a null checker, but it fails, I am a bit confused, how do I go about this ?

My confusion lies with this line >>     `Id ?? null ? user.UserId() ;`

heres my code

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult GetUserById (int ? Id)
{
     var user = new GetAuthenticatedUser() ;  /// This is a custom inhouse code that returns the User ID and properties

    Id ?? null ? user.UserId() ;  // I am trying to test if the Id is null then use the user account, if not user the query string Id value
     var userId = _user.GetUserBasedOnId(Id)
 
}
```

// In a nutshell what I am trying to achieve is this

```
if (Id == null )
{
         var userId = _user.GetUserBasedOnId(user.UserId)
}
else
{
         var userId = _user.GetUserBasedOnId(Id)
}
```

If I tried

```
Id = Id ?? null ? user.UserId() ;
```

I get the error

> CS0019 Operator ?? cannot be applied to operants of type int and

Comment: Your expression ``Id ?? null ? user.UserId()`` is not used anywhere, did you want ``Id = Id ?? null ? user.UserId()`` maybe?  or ``var userId = _user.GetUserBasedOnId( Id ?? null ? user.UserId())``

Comment: hi @ChristopherHamkins  I was getting the error, CS0019 Operator ?? cannot be applied to operants of type int and <null>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the int as nullable by changing

`public PartialViewResult GetUserById (int ? Id)`

to

`public PartialViewResult GetUserById (int? Id)`

Answer (score 0):

3 flavors, depending on the language version and the prototype of `GetUserBasedOnId`:

```
// inline coalesce, yields an int value
var userId = _user.GetUserBasedOnId(Id ?? user.UserId());
```

or

```
// Change to Id if it is null, retains int? type
Id ??= user.UserId()
var userId = _user.GetUserBasedOnId(Id);
```

or

```
// New variable, of type int instead of int?
var id = Id ?? user.UserId()
var userId = _user.GetUserBasedOnId(id);
```

Eventually, you can replace `user` with `new GetAuthenticatedUser()` (and get rid of the very first instruction) to avoid unnecessary calls to the method when `Id` is not null.

Note:
`Id ?? null` is useless, because it will yield the contents of Id (being null or not).